# Unmarshal JSON and differentiate between missing key and null value

Tags: json, api, go

I'm working with an application API that treats a missing key and a `null` value in JSON differently. It might hand back JSON like `{"value":null}` or `{}` - and they mean different things if the key is present. My problem is I need to Unmarshal the data into a `struct` and then Marshal back to JSON, preserving this nuance.

If I define a struct like:

```golang
type Test struct {
    Value *string `json:"value,omitempty"`
}
```

Then `{"value":null}` gets Marshalled to JSON as `{}`.

If I define a struct like:

```golang
type Test struct {
    Value *string `json:"value"`
}
```

Then `{}` gets Marshalled to JSON as `{"value":null}`.

Is there a way to handle null and missing key read from JSON and preserve the difference in missing key versus a null value?

Comment: Marshal into a map or json.RawMessage or own implementation of json.Unmarshaler. Increasing complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to distinguish between a null-value and nonexistence of a field, you can use `json.RawMessage`:

```
type Test struct {
    Value json.RawMessage `json:"value,omitempty"`
}
```

You can test `string(test.Value)=="null"` and `len(test.Value)==0` to figure out which case happened.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interfaces on a custom string type and use the "null byte" to signal `null`. However you'll need to make sure that other parts of your system that rely on the custom string type are aware of the null byte and that they handle such instances appropriately.

```golang
type String string

const Null String = "\x00"

func (s *String) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == "null" {
        *s = Null
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*string)(s))
}

func (s String) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if s == Null {
        return []byte(`null`), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(string(s))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HoiP778TDva

Comment: The final `string(s)` is not escaped. If it contains `"` it will produce invalid `JSON`.

Comment: @colm.anseo thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer that should handle that scenario as well.

Comment: You could just call Marshal direct: https://play.golang.org/p/YEEbZp8lu70

Comment: @colm.anseo Thanks, again.

Comment: Almost :-) your playground link uses `json.Marshal(s)` which causes infinite recursion. Should be: `json.Marshal(string(s))`

Comment: -_- I'm blaming that on food, I had way too much to eat.